# Getting the distances from multiple points to multiple lines in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am looking for advice on how to tackle this problem. I have many points and I want to find a list of the nearest lines to each of those points, in order, and export it to excel.

Here is a description of my inputs:

1. 5 lines (from KMZ files) within a few meters of eachother, sometimes
   crossing, many miles long
2. QGIS layer with many points, each point on *one* of the aforementioned lines

Desired output:

5 additional columns in the attribute table, each noting the nearest line, and if possible, the perpendicular distance to that line.

Things I have considered, and issues:

- Drawing circles with different radii on each point. Then trying an
  overlay analysis.
- Nearest Neighbors method, but I am new to QGIS and Python and cant
  figure out how to do this for multiple lines and points. QGIS only lets me (as far as I can tell) get the first nearest neighbor, whereas I need multiple

Comment: Just to clarify : _"each point on one of the aforementioned lines"_ :
1) are you sure these points strictly **intersect** the line ?
2) if yes is this line the nearest or do u intend to find the **next** nearest ?

Comment: 1) The points are technically each supposed to be on one of the lines, but they come from two different data sources so I cannot guarantee this to be the truth. 2) I want to find the distances to all of the other lines

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.